# find the closest vertex to a point in space

Tags: python, mesh

When i want to find the vertex within a mesh object that is closest to a given point in space,
i can do something like this:

```
import bpy
p     = Vector((1,1,1))
ob    = bpy.context.object
me    = ob.data
verts = me.vertices
distances = [(v.co - p).length for v in verts]
val, idx = min((val, idx) for (idx, val) in enumerate(distances))
```

Then idx is the index of the closest vertex.

But is there is a ready made function available that gives back the index of the closest vertex ?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that there is a single function for that, but you can use the `mathutils.kdtree` module to query closest points.

If you sort the vertices of your mesh into a kd-tree you can just call

```
co, index, dist = my_kd_tree.find(p)
```

`co` will contain the coordinates of the closest point, `index` its index and `dist` the distance between `p` and the closest point. See the [module documentation](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/mathutils.kdtree.html) for the complete example.

If you want to query many closest points, using the kd-tree will be much faster than iterating over all vertices.

Comment: Is this similar to ICP?

Comment: Do you mean Iterative Closest Point registration? Then no, this will just give you the closest point to coordinate `p` and not register meshes.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think there's a tool in blender to do dense correspondence between models, or is there?

Comment: Not out of the box, as far as I know. There is a (paid) addon for ICP, though: https://www.blendermarket.com/products/icp-iterative-closest-point-registration-addon